# Custom Interpolation on Pandas quantile function?

Tags: python, r, pandas, statistics

I need to implement R's quantile function type 3 in pandas, which is according to documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/quantile), nearest even order statistic.

Pandas only has basic ones like lower, higher, linear, nearest. (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

How do I implement the nearest even order interpolation on pandas?

Comment: Can this help you? [scipy.stats.mstats.mquantiles](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.mquantiles.html)